# Proxmox IOMMU Passthrough crashes host

Tags: proxmox

I am building a small home server with Proxmox. In my system i have installed:

- Asus A520m-k
- Ryzen 5 Pro 5650G
- 1x SATA Controller (via PCIe)
- 1x PCIe to M.2 Adapter with an NVME Drive

Now I want to setup a NAS, where I want to virtualize TrueNas Core. I want to passthrough the SATA Controller with 2x 2TB HDDs to the TrueNas instance via IOMMU.

I have enabled IOMMU in the UEFI of my motherboard, I also have setup IOMMU according to the offical Proxmox VE Wiki https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Pci_passthrough

With [this](https://gist.github.com/flungo/428c374c040de1d0a30fd4a593d39040) script i have listed all the IOMMU Groups with their devices:

```
IOMMU Group 1 00:01.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1633]
IOMMU Group 2 00:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1632]
IOMMU Group 3 00:02.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1634]
IOMMU Group 4 00:08.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1632]
IOMMU Group 4 00:08.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus [1022:1635]
IOMMU Group 4 00:08.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus [1022:1635]
IOMMU Group 4 08:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne [1002:1638] (rev d9)
IOMMU Group 4 08:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:1637]
IOMMU Group 4 08:00.2 Encryption controller [1080]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor [1022:15df]
IOMMU Group 4 08:00.3 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1 [1022:1639]
IOMMU Group 4 08:00.4 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1 [1022:1639]
IOMMU Group 4 08:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
IOMMU Group 4 09:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1022:7901] (rev 81)
IOMMU Group 5 00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:790b] (rev 51)
IOMMU Group 5 00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:790e] (rev 51)
IOMMU Group 6 00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:166a]
IOMMU Group 6 00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:166b]
IOMMU Group 6 00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:166c]
IOMMU Group 6 00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:166d]
IOMMU Group 6 00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:166e]
IOMMU Group 6 00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:166f]
IOMMU Group 6 00:18.6 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1670]
IOMMU Group 6 00:18.7 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1671]
IOMMU Group 7 01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Sandisk Corp WD Blue SN550 NVMe SSD [15b7:5009] (rev 01)
IOMMU Group 8 02:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43ec]
IOMMU Group 8 02:00.1 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43eb]
IOMMU Group 8 02:00.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43e9]
IOMMU Group 8 03:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43ea]
IOMMU Group 8 03:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43ea]
IOMMU Group 8 03:02.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43ea]
IOMMU Group 8 03:03.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43ea]
IOMMU Group 8 04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
IOMMU Group 8 06:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device [1b21:1064] (rev 02)
```

The SATA Controller i want to passthrough is the last device from `ASMedia Technology Inc.`

The problem that occurs is, that when i assigned the controller to my VM (currently only running ubuntu) and start it, the Proxmox VE hypervisor kinda crashes, not entirely i can still use the debian shell of Proxmox via keyboard and mouse, but the WEB interface is not active anymore and ssh also don't work. I don't have any clue about IOMMU but what i think happens is that the `Ethernet controller` which is also located in IOMMU group 8 also gets passed trough to the VM and so my Hypervisor is missing it's connection to my Router. (So i would also think that all devices located in group 8 will be passed to the VM).

I don't know if that what I think happens is right, but how would i fix it, so i can only passthrough the SATA Controller with my HDDs.

P.S. If there is any additional log needed notify me, I would like to provide it :D